# Simple use of Scala collections from Java not compiling with 2.11

Tags: java, scala, scala-2.11

So I've got this super exciting Java class:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream;

public class EmptyStreamFactory {
  public static Stream<String> createEmptyStringStream() {
    return Stream.<String>empty();
  }
}
```

Compiles just fine with the 2.10.4 `scala-library.jar` on the classpath (or 2.9.2, for what that's worth). Now I try it with 2.11:

```
EmptyStreamFactory.java:5: error: incompatible types
    return Stream.<String>empty();
                               ^
  required: Stream<String>
  found:    GenTraversable
1 error
```

How does this make any sense at all? At a glance the only difference that could be remotely relevant is the fact that `Stream.Empty` no longer extends `Serializable` in 2.11, but I don't see how that could cause this problem. The same thing happens with `List`, etc.

There's an easy workaround—you can just cast to the appropriate type—but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

(I'm on Oracle's JDK, version 1.7.0_67.)

Comment: `Stream.Empty` still extends `Serializable`, because it extends `Stream`. The removed `Serializable` on `Empty` was superfluous, so this can't be the source of your issue.

Answer (score 4):

The static forwarder for the bridge method isn't marked as a bridge method itself, and java for whatever reason prefers the one returning GenTraversable as it has two to choose from.

```
classOf[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[_]].getMethods filterNot 
  (_.isBridge) filter (_.getName == "empty") foreach println
public static scala.collection.immutable.Stream scala.collection.immutable.Stream.empty()
public static scala.collection.GenTraversable scala.collection.immutable.Stream.empty()
```

You can't overload on return type in java the language so it's anyone's guess what the compiler will do when it encounters it. I don't know if it's even specified, although it may be.

In general you [can't call collections methods from java](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4389), and this has been judged wontfix.

Edit: re "still don't understand what changed in 2.11 to make this happen", here is an initial batch of candidates:

```
% git log --no-merges --oneline --grep=forwarder v2.10.4..v2.11.2
532ef331eb (pull/3868/head) Restore reporter forwarders in CompilationUnit
b724201383 Rip out reporting indirection from CompilationUnit
98216be3f3 Move reporting logic into Reporting trait
653c404d7f (pull/3493/head) SI-3452 GenBCode version of the static-forwarder signature fix
640e279500 SI-3452 A better fix for static forwarder generic sigs
f8d80ea26a SI-3452 Correct Java generic signatures for mixins, static forwarders
51ec62a8c3 (pull/3480/head) SI-6948 Make the Abstract* classes public.
731ed385de SI-8134 SI-5954 Fix companions in package object under separate comp.
3cc99d7b4a (pull/3103/head) Collections library tidying and deprecation.  Separate parts are listed below.
5d29697365 Flesh out the Delambdafy phase.
6e2cadb8bd (pull/2951/head) SI-7847 Static forwarders for case apply/unapply
9733f56c87 (pull/1173/head) Fixes SI-4996.
```

You're not going to find it by looking at the library code, that much is certain. It's a change in the compiler.

Comment: This isn't you talking about Scala? from the link: `I played with it until it got too tedious.`

Comment: Ha ha, looks like martin and I agree on something as long as "it" is a type parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Still don't understand what changed in 2.11 to make this happen, but oh well. Would you suggest a specific workaround?

Comment: Sorry, my only suggestions would be in the vein of "don't expect this to work."

Comment: Actually, IIRC from last night, the last thing it will try with two abstract members w/same erasure is to take the most specific return type. OK, that's the end of 15.12.2.5.

Answer (score 2):

What I learned today is that Java is happy to ignore an extraneous type arg (JLS 15.12.2.1, fine print at the end of the section).

> This rule stems from issues of compatibility and principles of
>   substitutability.

Apparently, some rules stem from principled reasoning, others from practical issues, and the occasional rule has dual parentage.

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ javap -classpath ~/scala-2.11.2/lib/scala-library.jar scala.collection.immutable.Stream | grep empty
  public static <A extends java/lang/Object> scala.collection.immutable.Stream<A> empty();
  public static scala.collection.GenTraversable empty();
apm@mara:~/tmp$ javap -classpath ~/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar scala.collection.immutable.Stream | grep empty
  public static <A extends java/lang/Object> scala.collection.immutable.Stream<A> empty();
  public static <A extends java/lang/Object> scala.collection.immutable.Stream<A> empty();
```

It looks like the forwarder to the bridge method was fixed.

This compiles:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream;
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream$;

public class EmptyStreamFactory {
    public static Stream<String> createEmptyStringStream() {
        return Stream$.MODULE$.<String>empty();
    }
}
```

I would need a three-day weekend to re-read the spec on overloading in Java.

Maybe because Stream is abstract, the rule for most-specific return type rule kicks in.

Comment: Thanks for the extra clue, but I still don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @TravisBrown The second signature comes from http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion but wasn't generated to produce GenTraversable, the upper bound. Now it is, and Java overloading selects it. For some reason, it selects it on Stream but not on Stream$.

Comment: On Stream$, the GenTraversable returning method is a bridge method. On Stream, it isn't.

Comment: @extempore Thanks, I noticed it last night but it didn't register. It's like the brain has to operate `exitingErasure(thunk)` so to speak in a different mode.